# Slicing -> not sure what -len does

Tags: python, slice

can someone explain how the output is `'b'` for `a[-len(a)]`?

```
a = "blueberry"
>>> a[-len(a)]
'b'
```

Comment: This is item access, not slicing.

Comment: Do you understand how negative indices work in general?  If not, look at [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a negative number is used as an index, internally, the length of the sequence is added to it, and the result is then used as the index.

So, what happens is:

```
a[-len(a)]
a[len(a)-len(a)]
a[0]
```

which is `b`.

Answer (score 2):

Negative indices count from the lastmost element starting at -1, and continue towards the beginning. Therefore a 3-element sequence has a length of 3, and -3 is the index of the first element.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html), you can use -len() to idicate the first char:

```
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+
 | P | y | t | h | o | n |
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+
 0   1   2   3   4   5   6
-6  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1
```

Comment: your image is not correct, there is no 6th index in this string, the len of the string is 6

Comment: Agrees the indexing will fail, this schema is form the python doc, and is quite visual to understand the indexing and the negative indexing. 6 is there as reference and 0 , and -0 will be first element.

Comment: @BallPython's comment misses the fact that the numbers are *between* elements rather than right below them.  This visualization is very helpful in understanding how ranges work in Python (for example, `a[1:5]`)